# Curl PHP doesn't get the data if passed a parameters

Tags: php

I tried to access an API from a specified URL, but it doesn't work.

**here's my code:**

```
$query = http_build_query([
    'origin' => '153',
    'destination' => (int)$_GET['city'],
    'weight' => (int)$_GET['weight'],
    'courier' => 'jne'
    //i even tried to pass method: get but it doesn't work
]);
$url = 'https://astrajingga.com/PROJECT/LPPIConnect/API/getDelivery.php' . $query;

$newCurl = curl_init($url);

// hidden, not the real authorization
$customHeaders = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);

curl_setopt($newCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $customHeaders);

curl_setopt($newCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($newCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($newCurl);

$myData = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($myData);
die();
```

when I dump it, it shows a good URL. I even tested it in `apitester.com` and it works. but when I run it via my web, it returns `NULL`.

Anything I miss here?

Comment: Are you sure that API is returning JSON? Are you sure these parameters should be passed as GET? If this is the case, you're missing a `?` between `getDelivery.php` and `$query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test try this

```html
<?php
$query = array(
            'origin' => '153',
            'destination' => 120,
            'weight' => 56,
            'courier' => 'jne'
            //i even tried to pass method: get but it doesn't work
        );**strong text**
       // $url = 'https://astrajingga.com/PROJECT/LPPIConnect/API/getDelivery.php' . $query;

        $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://astrajingga.com/PROJECT/LPPIConnect/API/getDelivery.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
        die();
```